# Api gateway in Node Js

Tags: node.js, express, api-gateway

I am wondering can somebody explain how to create a Api gateway in Node js. Most of the answer I have seen using the express-http-proxy.

So my question is proxy server and Api gateway are the same?. If it's different means explain it how?